# Java: Are these 2 codes the same?

Tags: java, foreach

```
for (Player p : players) 
{
  p.addCard(deck.dealCard());
  p.addCard(deck.dealCard());
}
```

and

```
  for (int i = 0; i < players.size() ; i++)
{
    Player p = players.get(i);
    p.addCard(deck.dealCard());
    p.addCard(deck.dealCard());
}
```

The second code yeilds a null pointer exception, what can be done to make the bottom one equivalent ?

Comment: What is the type for players?

Comment: could you please be a bit more specific as where the Exception is thrown SVP?

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at PokerGame.dealRound(PokerGame.java:105)
 at PokerGame.play(PokerGame.java:38)
 at PokerGame.main(PokerGame.java:202)



line 105 is         p.addCard(deck.dealCard());

Comment: Which is line 105?  What is the type of the collection you are iterating across?  Does it fail every time, or only under certain circumstances (eg, if a player leaves during the loop)?

Comment: If you want a better understanding of the loop, dump more state. Print the values of everything between every statement. Or better, step through it with a debugger. There's no better way to understand the code than to analyze the execution in fine-grained detail. We could provide more help if the question was more detailed, specifically, the type of Players and definition of Player.

Comment: Line 105 is PokerGame.main(PokerGame.java:202) the top one. It fails every time I execute the program, while the for-each one doesn't fail at all.

Comment: Fully agree with @nicerobot. You should step through the code with a debugger and find out exactly what is it that's throwing the NullPointerException. Unless there's some magic happening in the code, both of these should work alike.

Comment: Stop forcing people to play games and just paste the stacktrace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can see this happening if `players` is a custom [`java.lang.Iterable`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html) who's `get()` implementation is broken, or at any rate, behaves in an unexpected manner (different from `java.util.List`'s behavior).

Other that that, the only thing I can think of is that something you're not showing us in your code is causing something to go terribly wrong.

What happens if you do this?

```
for (Iterator<Player> playerIter = players.iterator(); playerIter.hasNext();) 
{
  Player p = playerIter.next();
  p.addCard(deck.dealCard());
  p.addCard(deck.dealCard());
}
```

Edit:

Just read [AZ's response](http://#2422348), and it's definitely possible that it's `size()` that has the odd behavior as well.

Comment: It says: "next() in java.util.Iterator cannot be applied to (int)"

Comment: @Kevin - change that to `playerIter.next()` and try again.

Comment: I apologize, I was just copying and pasting your code, and forgot to remove the parameter. I'll update for correctness.

Answer (score 3):

This is going to be a very wild guess: it might be possible that `size()` does not yield the number of Player in players but the total capacity of players. And, the Iterator for players iterates only over the allocated items.

So to answer your question from the title, those two snippets of code are not necessarily the same. The for-each structure uses an iterator and the creator of the code could have used any implementation he considered the most suitable for whatever players' type is.

Your `for-each` structure's `for` equivalent should look more like this:

```
for (Iterator<Player> i = players.iterator(); i.hasNext(); ){
        Player p = i.next();
        //... Your code here
}
```

Comment: I substituted this so it looked like the below code and it still yields the same null pointer exception.

 for (Iterator<Player> i = players.iterator(); i.hasNext(); 
{
    Player p = i.next();
    p.addCard(deck.dealCard());
    p.addCard(deck.dealCard());
}

Answer (score 2):

Without knowing more details about `Player`, you could do the obvious thing and check that `p` is null before referencing it.

Comment: but p works fine in the first one
why doesn't it work in the bottom instance (if the 2 statements are equal)?

Comment: @Kevin: That would be because the iterator [implicitly] used for the first snippet uses a different way to detect the "size".

Comment: @Kevin: Another possibility is that the iterator is filtering out `null` values in the "collection".

Comment: @Kevin: it will be good if instead of just start processing player, you try `if ( null != p ) { // code here `

Answer (score 1):

Since the line `p.addCard(deck.dealCard());` is throwing the NullPointerException then either

1. p is null or
2. deck is null or
3. dealCard() method is causing the exception somewhere.

If at all possible you should use the Iterator for Collections.

```
Iterator<Player> iter = players.iterator();
while(iter.hasNext()){
   Player p = iter.next();
   p.addCard(deck.dealcard());
   //etc.
}
```

Comment: yes, exactly the same, I'm just trying to rewrite this for-each loop to get a better understanding of it

Answer (score 1):

One scenario I can think of where a `NullPointerException` will be thrown in the second case is when `addCard` or `dealCard` somehow changes what `players` refer to (presumably neither modifies the content of `players`, because that would cause a `ConcurrentModificationException` in the first snippet).

Here's an example (please run this on your own if you have any doubts):

```
import java.util.*;

public class ForEachVS {
    static List<Integer> players;
    static void process(int i) {
        System.out.println(i);
        players = null;
    }
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        players = Arrays.asList(1,2,3);
        for (int p : players) {
            process(p);
        } // this processes 1,2,3
        players = Arrays.asList(1,2,3);
        for (int i = 0; i < players.size(); i++) {
            process(players.get(i));
        } // this processes 1, then throws NullPointerException
    }
}
```

So as you can see, the two constructs are actually NOT exactly equivalent. The essence of the above snippet is concisely presented here:

```
    int[] arr;

    arr = new int[5];
    for (int x : arr) {
        arr = null;
    }

    arr = new int[5];
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        arr = null;
    }
```

You will find out that the first loop went fine, while the second loop throws `NullPointerException`. So while it's true most of the time, *the two constructs are not exactly 100% equivalent*.

Answer (score 0):

The only difference with the to snippets is the method of getting a value for p. In the first java is iterating over players, in the second you are doing it explicitly. The most likely cause of the null pointer error is p being null. If deck was null both snippets would throw a null exception. The same is true of addCard and dealCard, if either method were to throw a null pointer error both snippets would do so.

It looks like java's for-each syntax is doing a check for null before executing the body of the loop.

This question talks about the difference:
[Java for each vs regular for -- are they equivalent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422690/java-for-each-vs-regular-for-are-they-equivalent)