# Simulate Traffic on a Road (as array) in Java

Tags: java, arrays, object

I have a project that is to create an array aRoad with a distinct length. I need to shift elements through this array and delete the object in the end, when it reaches the element just behind aRoad[N].

Let's suppose:
I have a number of objects ("cars") N and an array ("road") with the length L (=4).

```
i = 0: car1 is at road[0].  
i = 1: car1 is at road[1].  
i = 2: car1 is at road[2], car2 spawns at road[0].  
i = 3: car1 is at road[3], car2 is at road[1].  
i = 4: car1 vanishes from the road, car2 is at road[2], car3 spawns at road[0].
```

My Car-class:

```
package traffic;
public class Vehicle {

private int bornTime;
private char destination;  

public Vehicle(int bornTime, char destination){
    this.bornTime = bornTime;
    this.destination = destination;
}

public int returnTime() {
    return bornTime;
}

public char returnDest() {
    return destination;
}

public String toString() {
    System.out.print(destination);
    return null;
}   
}
```

My problem is: as soon as an object is leaving the array I get an error because the Index is out of Range. I tried to cover this with an IF-condition and thanks to the first answer I was able to create the code update.

How do I get a system, like that to run in Java? My updated approach:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
int time = 1;
char[] aRoad = new char[6]; // lane length
Vehicle[] carList = {new Vehicle(1, 'X'), new Vehicle(4, 'Y')};

    while(time < 15){
        for(Vehicle car : carList){
        if (car != null ){
            int pos = time - car.returnTime();
        if (pos >= 0){
            if (pos >= 1){
                aRoad[pos-1] = 0;
            }
            if (pos == (aRoad.length)){
                aRoad[pos-1] = 0;
                car = null;
            }
            if (car != null){
                aRoad[pos] = car.returnDest();
            }
        }
        }
        }
//PRINT ARRAY EACH ITERATION, SET time = time + 1
}
```

The output looks like:

```
[...]
time = 6: [ ,  , Y,  ,  , X]
time = 7: [ ,  ,  , Y,  ,  ]
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 6
at traffic.Test1.main(Test1.java:19)
```

So my specific question is:
How do I prevent this exception without setting the X-object (-car) to `null`?

**EDIT**
Since the question was too unspecified I threw out all the useless information and tidied it up.

Comment: What exactly is your question? Right now it's in danger of getting closed because it's basically too broad.

Comment: Okay, to make it more specific: I need to construct a car of class Vehicle every 2 seconds for example. These car shall then shift through the array called road and get deleted when reaching the end: a) how do I create and label for example 5 cars? And how do I shift the position by checking if array [i+1] is unoccupied, and, b) how can I delete each car when reaching array [end]. Is that more specific?

Comment: Yes this is specific and it's also Java basics. Limit yourself to one question at the time and post your current progress on that matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will answer your most clear question, the answer to which should hopefully set you in the right direction.

> but how do I actually create a lot of cars going down the road?

You may be getting stuck here because you haven't utilised your Vehicle object's `borntime` field. For each iteration of your while loop, a car's new position in the road should be be given by

```
current time - borntime
```

So if you have multiple cars and a while loop iterating over your time dimension

```
Vehicle car1 = new Vehicle(2, "X");
Vehicle car2 = new Vehicle(4, "Y");   
...
int time = 2;
while(time < 10){
   // calculate road positions
   int car1Pos = time - car1.returnTime();
   int car2Pos = time - car2.returnTime();

   aRoad[car1Pos - 1] = 0;
   aRoad[car1Pos] = car1.returnDest();

   aRoad[car2Pos - 1] = 0;
   aRoad[car2Pos] = car1.returnDest();
   ...
}
```

But whenever your code starts looking this repetitive its best to think in terms of more arrays and loops. Put the vehicles in a "Vehicle array" and loop over it to update each car's position in the array

```
Vehicle[] carList = {new Vehicle(2, "X"), new Vehicle(4, "Y")};
...
int time = 2;
while(time < 10){
    for(Vehicle car : carList){
         int pos = time - car.returnTime();
         aRoad[pos-1] = 0;
         aRoad[pos] = car.returnDest();
    }
    ...
}
```

Once you have that working, the next step would be to dynamically add Vehicles to `carList`, perhaps every two seconds, and remove them from `carList` when they get to the end of the road. Using an `ArrayList` for your `carList` would be much easier for this part.

Note that I have not tested this code so their might be syntactic mistakes.

Comment: Hej! Thanks for your response! This was in the first instance really helpful. I am just trying to implement and extend it and will give you then further feedback!

Comment: I created a list of cars, as you suggested. Not doing that, but creating 2 discrete cars works now. Using the list, it still crashes (see above). How exactly does this `for(Vehicle car : carList)` work in Java? I updated my question on the top with a better code excerpt.

Comment: You need another `if` statement to check that the Vehicle's position is still within the bounds of your road array. If it is, you can then shift it's destination character. If it isn't, you should just remove its character from the road array. The for loop is just a simplified notation, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5851025/why-are-there-two-different-kinds-of-for-loops-in-java

Comment: I am quite happy now with what you told me and how I could implement it. If I might ask one other thing about the declaration of objects in arrays.
When the car-object is deleted from the last position, I want to call a method to tell me how many time-steps it took, to move through an array.
How do I call the object sitting on the last array if I have an inifinte flow of objects going through? Something like: 
`IF carX on aRoad[end], THEN call carX.getInformation() THEN set carX = null` but I don't know the index of the car?

Comment: The way it is set up right now, you won't be able to tell when a particular Vehicle object is at the end of your road. You need some way of linking your Vehicle objects to their state on the road. A simple solution to this is to have some field `int roadPosition` in your Vehicle object that stores the current position of the Vehicle on your road, and some method `moveVehicle(int newRoadPos)` that allows you to update the position when needed. You can then check to see if the vehicle is at the end of the road with some kind of check like `vehicle.getRoadPosition() == aRoad.length - 1`

Comment: I see, I think the way to solve it will lead me to a different approach for the whole simulation, but once again: thanks for helping out! I will keep this in mind just in case