# What is the meaning of this snippet in junit?

Tags: java, junit

What does "result" store and what does the line Failure failure: result.getFailures() do in the for loop of a Test Runner

```
import org.junit.runner.*;
public class Runners
{
public static void main(String args[])
{
Result result= JUnitCore.runClasses(Test1.class,Test2.class);
for(Failure failure:result.getFailures())
{
System.out.println(failure.toString());
}
System.out.println(result.wasSuccessful());
}
}
```

Comment: Check the API: https://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/latest/org/junit/runner/JUnitCore.html#runClasses(java.lang.Class...) and https://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/latest/org/junit/runner/Result.html

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Stackoverflow!
The documentation of a given framework/API/tool can tell a lot. Therefore it is a good place to start to understand how it works.

The `result` variable is the concatenated results of the two test classes.
[As the documentation says](https://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/latest/org/junit/runner/Result.html):

> A Result collects and summarizes information from running multiple tests. All tests are counted -- additional information is collected from tests that fail.

Therefore the for loop gets each `Failure` and writes them out to the console:

> Returns the Failures describing tests that failed and the problems they encountered

After the `wasSuccesful()` is written out which is either true or false. Depending on *if all tests succeded*

To answer the comment about the `:`.

It is a standard Java for-each loop. The loop will be executed with each element of the array. [This geeksforgeeks page](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/for-each-loop-in-java/) describes it better than I could and have examples how to use it.

Comment: Is the colon part of the syntax of fetching individual failure descriptions(ie. Failure failure : result.getFailures()) or does it have a general purpose in loops? Because I have never seen colon in for loops in java

Comment: The colon is just a shorter way of writing a for loop of collections, it basically just says 'for every object in collection'. I like the explanation given here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5851025/why-are-there-two-different-kinds-of-for-loops-in-java